# How to convert any text or letter to image in javafx

Tags: java, image, text, javafx

I have a Text object, where is something written - a letter or sentence. How can I convert this text into an image in javafx and then show it as image. I can't use Labels, because I need to have possibility of editing any pixel of this converted image.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Create a Text object and call its [snapshot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot-javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-) method.  A Label will have more styling options, including background.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
private WritableImage textToImage(String text) {

    Text t = new Text(text);
    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(t));
    return t.snapshot(null, null);
}
```